# Need to handle the query string "/projects?technologies=AI&industries=Security" Using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter, query-string, querystringparameter

This is my first time to create a query string parameter, So please help me out.

- I want to filter the data based json field 'technologies, industries and maturity'
  every field(technologies, industries and maturity) have an array of elements. I want to filter
  that element of every field.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbNGR.png)
- I wrote the backend code:

```js
const { pick } = require('lodash');

const toArray = props =>
  (props && props.split ? props.split(',') : props || []).map(item => item.trim());
 console.log("this is in filter props: ", toArray)

module.exports = (entities, query) => {

  const fields = toArray(query.pick);
  const industries = toArray(query.industries);
  const technologies = toArray(query.technologies);
  const maturity = toArray(query.maturity);


  return entities.reduce((accumulator, entity) => {
    const hasTecnology = technologies.length

      ? technologies.every(technology => entity.technologies && entity.technologies.includes(technology))
      : true;
    
    const hasIndustury = industries.length
      ? industries.every(industry => entity.industries && entity.industries.includes(industry))
      : true;
    
      const hasMaturity = maturity.length
      ? maturity.every(maturty => entity.maturity && entity.maturity.includes(maturty))
      : true;
    const condition = hasTecnology && hasIndustury && hasMaturity;

    return condition
      ? [...accumulator, fields.length ? pick(entity, fields) : entity]
      : accumulator;
  }, []);
};
```

- My controller function:

```js
  async find(ctx) {
    const { query } = ctx.request;
    const email = ctx.state.user.email; 
    const userProjects = strapi.cache.users[email].displayCatalog;

    let projects = strapi.cache.projects.filter(project => userProjects.includes(project.slug));

    if (query.pick || query.industries || query.technologies || query.maturity) {
      projects = filter(projects, query);
    }
    return buildResponse(projects.map(project => hideSensitive(project, userProjects, email)));
  },
```

- This code is valid for only single parameter "/projects?technologies=AI" but I am trying to get "/projects?technologies=AI&industries=Security&maturity=Experimentation" this type filter usign query string.

**Note: If we select technologies field's element ex- Security or industries field's element ex- AI data will will show both technologies Security and industries AI.**

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

you can query for all fields.

place this in controller.js file.

```
        const queryObj = { ...req.query };
        let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
     
        queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte|eq|ne)\b/g, match => `$${match}`);

        console.log(queryStr);

       const doc1 = await Model.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
```

In the above code

```
api/projects?technologies[eq]="AI"&industries[eq]="Security"
```

Comment: - I added but not worked. I needed only data which I put on the string but this is give me whole array of the db.
could you please check this?

Answer (score 0):

- Thanks for Idea I changed some code and get the solution.

```js
const toArray = props =>
  (props && props.split ? props.split(',') : props || []).map(item => item.trim());

const hasField = (entity, fields) => {
  if (!fields.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i + 1) {
    if (entity && entity.includes(fields[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

module.exports = (entities, query) => {
  const industries = toArray(query.industries);
  const technologies = toArray(query.technologies);
  const maturity = toArray(query.maturity);

  return entities.filter(entity => {
    const hasTecnology = hasField(entity.industries, industries);
    const hasIndustury = hasField(entity.technologies, technologies);
    const hasMaturity = hasField(entity.maturity, maturity);

    const condition = hasTecnology || hasIndustury || hasMaturity;

 
    if (condition) {
      return entity;
    }
    return null;
  }, []);
};
```

- My controller will same